# Xcode app dump returns empty SQLite file generated by coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

Im trying to debug my coredata generated database.

I've downloaded app container, it has everything except sqlite file with data.

To make sure my changes are saved, I've quit the application.

How can I get Sqlite file with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that SQlite db only gets updated when you kill the app. It doesnt work if you have debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

Just debug your managedObjectContext, see the PersistentStoreCoordinator attribute, there is a url to show the real store path. It may be not a file named '*.sqlite', or it may be store in different bundle , or it may be store in the remote server. Just print it out to see.

Comment: I can confirm, Im checking the right path. Also this problem is not unique to my current project, it seems dump might be returned from last time device is synced.

Comment: Why do not you call [save:] in NSManagedObjectContext. So you can save the data to it. Then wait until seconds to download file.

Comment: good idea, plus it seems that itunes is also having trouble with my device. Its giving me error periodically "Sync failed, device stopped responding". My phone is not jailbroken and itunes is latest version. :(

Comment: I think you can try another device.